# How to join a file of characters by line respecting blank lines using while in shell script?

Tags: scripts

File **input.txt** contains:

```
*
*
*
 
 
H 
E 
L 
L 
O 
 
W
O
R
L
D
 
 
*
*
*
```

My code reads each character by line:

```
while read -n1 c; do
     dest+="${c}"
done < input.txt

echo $dest
```

Result is:

```
***HELLOWORLD***
```

I want this:

***  HELLO WORLD  ***

Comment: This ... looks like a homework question 

Comment: Does the lines without visible characters contain a space or nothing (just a linefeed) ?

Comment: It looks easy, but is not easy.

Comment: The lines without visible characters contains nothing.  I put spaces but the result is the same.  No spaces appear.

Comment: use `while IFS= read -r -n1 c` -- because space is in the default IFS variable, read is ignoring the space on the "blank" lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the bash shell because of the `-n1` option, which is not part of the POSIX `sh` standard.

If you drop the `-n1`, then `read` will assign a value to `c` only on non-empty lines. You can then use a parameter expansion of the form

```
   ${parameter:-word}
          Use  Default  Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expan‐
          sion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of  parameter
          is substituted.
```

to assign a default value of <kbd>Space</kbd> when `c` is empty. So

```
#!/bin/bash

while read c; do
    dest+=${c:- }
done < input.txt

echo "$dest"
```

Note that variable expansions don't need to be quoted on the RHS of an assignment - but should be quoted in the `echo` command else `$dest` will be subject to word-splitting and filename generation ("globbing") by the shell - particularly important when the variable may contain `*` characters.

Then given

```
$ cat input.txt
*
*
*


H
E
L
L
O

W
O
R
L
D


*
*
*
```

you should get

```
$ ./myscript
***  HELLO WORLD  ***
```

Comment: Your recommendation is good, but don't display the asterisks.  May be need to escape the asterisks.  This is my result: input.txt script.sh HELLO WORLD input.txt script.sh

Comment: ```input.txt scrolling.sh
input.txt scrolling.sh
input.txt scrolling.sh


H
E
L
L
O


W
O
R
L
D


input.txt scrolling.sh
input.txt scrolling.sh
input.txt scrolling.sh```

Comment: scrolling.sh is the scriptname.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ paste -sd "" < input.txt
***  H E L L O  WORLD  ***
```

The sample text in your question, that I cut-and-pasted, has some extra spaces in it.